# Python using givens rotation for QR decomposition

Tags: python, numpy

I need help defining a function to compute the QR decomposition of a matrix using rotators and a conditional to check if a number is nearly zero before applying a rotator (tolerance of 1e-15)

```
import numpy as np     
A = np.array(([(1,-2,3),(0,-1,4),(0,2,5)]))

def QRrot(A):
  m,n = A.shape
  indexI = np.zeros(m,n)
  indexJ = np.zeros(m,n)
  C = np.zeros(m,n)
  S = np.zeros(m,n)
  for i in range(1, n):
      for j in range(i+1, m):
          c = A(i,i)/((A(i,i))**2 + (A(j,i)**2))**0.5;
          s = A(j,i)/((A(i,i))**2 + (A(j,i)**2))**0.5;
          A[i,:] = c*A[i,:] + s*A[j,:];
          A[j,:] = -s*A[i,:] + c*A[j,:];
          indexI[j,i] = i;
          indexJ[j,i] = j;
          C[j,i] = c;
          S[j,i] = s;
          R = A
          Q = np.eye(m)
          Q[:,i] = c*Q[:,i] + s*Q[:,j];
          Q[:,j] = -s*Q[:,i] + c*Q[:,j];

return(Q,R)
```

Comment: I haven't look into the QR decomposition itself, but careful with `R = A`. When you do that both `R` and `A` will point to the same array, meaning that changing elements in one will affect the other. That is **not** what you want. Use `R = A.copy()` instead.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html